# Pyspark Dataframes to Pandas and ML Ops - Parallel Execution Hold?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

If I convert a spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe and subsequently apply pandas operations and sklearn models to the dataset in databricks, will the operations from pandas and sklearn be distributed across the cluster? Or do i have to use pyspark dataframe operations and pyspark ml packages for operations to be distributed?

Comment: If you find the answer suitable, you can use the little hidden tick under the Up/down vote to accept the answer. Welcome to community.

Comment: See also https://github.com/databricks/koalas which is a pandas work-alike API that implements the operations on Spark, without using Pyspark APIs

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **NO**.

The moment you convert the spark dataframe into a pandas dataframe, all of the subsequent  operations (pandas, ml etc.) will be run on a single-core as those algorithms and programs are written in native-python and doesn't support multi-core distributions. In a nutshell, someone has to rewrite the whole sklearn to again to be compatible with spark.

Said that there are some progress to bring e.g. to distribute scikit-learn on a Spark cluster. Some functionalities like the expensive GridSearch are rewritten in spark and you can use it together with native sklearn in databricks, see [**this post**](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html), or **[Joblib Apache Spark Backend](https://github.com/joblib/joblib-spark)** (previously known as [spark-sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn)). This [**blog post**](https://medium.com/civis-analytics/prediction-at-scale-with-scikit-learn-and-pyspark-pandas-udfs-51d5ebfb2cd8) is also worth reading as well.